# What is a good size for clickable area on mobile devices?

Tags: usability, touchscreen, mobile-devices

I am looking for some guidelines or suggestion, on what is a "good" size for clickable elements when developing for mobile devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the common resolution for smart phones like iphone is 320x480.

so maybe go for the size of a finger , like about 44x44.

look here [minimum-sensible-button-size-on-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928991/minimum-sensible-button-size-on-iphone)

Comment: is this 44x44 pt in CSS? (not PX)?

Answer (score 0):

If the mobile device is not touch sensitive (using stylus) then visible 5mm x 5mm can be fine. Exact pixel values depends on the displays dpi (dot per inch) parameter