# Standard button size in new iPhone(640*960)

Tags: iphone

what is the standard size of buttons in  iPhone(640*960) as specified by Apple Inc.

Comment: Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928991/minimum-sensible-button-size-on-iphone

Comment: Be more specific. What do you mean by a button? And there is no difference in size between retina and non-retina devices - on screen content is measured in points, not pixels, and the retina device just has twice as many pixels in each dimension.

Comment: Related to @Rushi's comment: The 960-by-640-pixel resolution translates to 326ppi = 12.835px/mm. Aiming for 9.2mm gives **118px diagonal**. This is not "as specified by Apple" but what research has shown, cf. the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are of size 44x44.

Images for toolbar and navigation icons should be 20x20,

and for tab bar icons should be 30x30.