# How to design sencha radio button

Tags: sencha-touch, radio-button, sencha-touch-2

I know how to create radio button in sencha, but i want to know " **how to design radio button like below** "

[image]

Comment: With CSS. Also those radio buttons would be a bit small for a touch device.

Comment: why not use a picker instead of radio buttons? As @TDeBailleul said, 4 radio button won't fit correctly if device width is less.

Comment: It's an android tablet application

Comment: That's not what I meant. I was more thinking about the size of the tappable area: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928991/minimum-sensible-button-size-on-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i did, almost i got it.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    layout: 'hbox',
    defaults: {
           labelWidth: '50%',
           labelAlign: 'right'
     },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            name : 'color',
            value: 'red',
            label: 'Red',
            checked: true
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            name : 'color',
            value: 'green',
            label: 'Green'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            name : 'color',
            value: 'blue',
            label: 'Blue'
        }
    ]
});
```