# Add padding to a UIButton that has no text

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton that is 36x36 and I want to add padding (in essence like CSS) so that the touchable area is [the recommended 44x44](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1929010/3498950).

I've tried adding edge inserts through the Interface Builder and also with the code below but nothing I've tried increases the touchable area.

```
resetButton.contentEdgeInsets.top = 50
resetButton.contentEdgeInsets.left = 50
```

Does an edge inset only work with buttons that include text?

[image]

**Update:**

- I've tried setting `contentEdgeInsets`, `imageEdgeInsets`, and `titleEdgeInsets` to no avail.
- I could expand touchable area by editing the actual image and increasing the border around the icon. (This wouldn't be the preferred way but I'll probably go this route if I can't find another solution.)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808503/uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area

Comment: That's for objective-c. I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I overwrote in Swift [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13067285/3004003) answer and it works:

```
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

private var KEY_HIT_TEST_EDGE_INSETS: String = "HitTestEdgeInsets"

extension UIButton {

    public func setHitTestEdgeInsets(inout hitTestEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets) {
        let value = NSValue(&hitTestEdgeInsets, withObjCType:NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero).objCType)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &KEY_HIT_TEST_EDGE_INSETS, value, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }

    private func hitTestEdgeInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &KEY_HIT_TEST_EDGE_INSETS)
        if (value != nil) {
            var edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            value.getValue(&edgeInsets)
            return edgeInsets
        } else {
            return UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
    }

    override public func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

        if UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(self.hitTestEdgeInsets(), UIEdgeInsetsZero) || !self.enabled || self.hidden  {
            return super.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)
        }

        let relativeFrame = self.bounds
        let hitFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(relativeFrame, self.hitTestEdgeInsets());

        return CGRectContainsPoint(hitFrame, point)
    }

}
```

Use:

```
var insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, -20, -20, -20)
button.setHitTestEdgeInsets(&insets)
```