# What are the button sizes on different iOS sizes

Tags: ios, user-interface

According to recommendations like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928991/minimum-sensible-button-size-on-iphone), the button size Apple recommends is 44x44. First, they seem to indicate these are in pixels and not points. So I would guess it means 44x44 pixels on 1x devices and 88x88 pixels on 2x devices and so forth. But when I tried 88x88 image button (UIImage) on my iPhone 6, it looks way too big. 44x44 looks exactly right; but then it would imply 22x22 on 1x devices? Is that 44x44 advice for 2x devices? What should be the button sizes in pixels on different iOS devices?

Comment: No, the 44x44 is points, not pixels. It should be 44points on every device.

Comment: but then it would mean 88x88 pixels on 2x device like iPhone 6? it seems really big.

Comment: That's correct. It will be 44px on 1x, 88px on 2x, and 132px on 3x. And those three buttons will look the same size if you hold the three devices next to each other.